# Django admin: how to predefine field values?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use Django 1.11.10 and python 3.6; I have `Category` model that has `name` and `parent`. Parent field links to itself. But when I create new `Category` model, I want choose parent from already created categories that have no parents. So how to predefine this list?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

------

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'parent']

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryForm

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: No category model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a drop down in the form when the a accesses the front end.

You can add this to your form:

```
parent = forms.forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Category.objects.all(), required = True)
```

So the final form would look like:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parent = forms.forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Category.objects.all(), required = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'parent']
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted!